# Apache Spark GroupBy / Aggregate

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

New Spark and using Java. How do I do the equivalent SQL below:

```
select id, sum(thistransaction::decimal) , date_part('month', transactiondisplaydate::timestamp) as month from history  group by id, month
```

Data Set looks like this:

```
ID, Spend, DateTime
468429,13.3,2017-09-01T11:43:16.999
520003,84.34,2017-09-01T11:46:49.999
520003,46.69,2017-09-01T11:24:34.999
520003,82.1,2017-09-01T11:45:19.999
468429,20.0,2017-09-01T11:40:14.999
468429,20.0,2017-09-01T11:38:16.999
520003,26.57,2017-09-01T12:46:25.999
468429,20.0,2017-09-01T12:25:04.999
468429,20.0,2017-09-01T12:25:04.999
520003,20.25,2017-09-01T12:24:51.999
```

The desired outcome is average weekly spend by customer.

This is more to do with which flow to use than the nuts and bolts of getting the data loaded etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
df=df.withColumn("Month", col("DateTime").substr(6, 2));
df=df.groupBy(col("ID"),col("Month")).agg(sum("Spend"));
df.show();
```

Which will produce

```
+------+-----+----------+
|    ID|Month|sum(Spend)|
+------+-----+----------+
|520003|   09|    259.95|
|468429|   09|      93.3|
+------+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version ...

```
val df = Seq(
(468429,13.3,"2017-09-01T11:43:16.999"),
(520003,84.34,"2017-09-01T11:46:49.999"),
(520003,46.69,"2017-09-01T11:24:34.999"),
(520003,82.1,"2017-09-01T11:45:19.999"),
(468429,20.0,"2017-09-01T11:40:14.999"),
(468429,20.0,"2017-09-12T11:38:16.999"),
(520003,26.57,"2017-09-22T12:46:25.999"),
(468429,20.0,"2017-09-01T12:25:04.999"),
(468429,20.0,"2017-09-17T12:25:04.999"),
(520003,20.25,"2017-09-01T12:24:51.999")
).toDF("id","spend","datetime")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df2 = df.select('id,'datetime,date_format($"datetime", "M").name("month"),
                        date_format($"datetime", "W").name("week"),'spend)

// Monthly

df2.groupBy('id,'month).agg(sum('spend).as("spend_sum"),avg('spend).as("spend_avg")).
select('id,'month,'spend_sum,'spend_avg).show()

+------+-----+---------+------------------+
|    id|month|spend_sum|         spend_avg|
+------+-----+---------+------------------+
|520003|    9|   259.95|51.989999999999995|
|468429|    9|     93.3|             18.66|
+------+-----+---------+------------------+

// Weekly

df2.groupBy('id,'month,'week).agg(sum('spend).as("spend_sum"),avg('spend).as("spend_avg")).
select('id,'month,'week,'spend_sum,'spend_avg).show()

+------+-----+----+---------+------------------+
|    id|month|week|spend_sum|         spend_avg|
+------+-----+----+---------+------------------+
|520003|    9|   4|    26.57|             26.57|
|468429|    9|   3|     20.0|              20.0|
|520003|    9|   1|   233.38|            58.345|
|468429|    9|   4|     20.0|              20.0|
|468429|    9|   1|     53.3|17.766666666666666|
+------+-----+----+---------+------------------+
```